# How can we generate DTD from class java

Tags: java, class, generator, dtd

I have a Java application. How can I generate a DTD from a Java class?
I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you would not use DTDs any more.

I assume you are using a serialize framework like JAXB. As a part of the jaxb distribution is schemagen. With schemagen you can create xsd file for your classes.

Have a look at this:

https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/docs/schemagen.html

Comment: No, I don't use JAXB, my app without framework so how can I generate DTD from this? any idea plz?

Comment: Use Jaxb, or its schemagen, to generate the schema files. You can how ever then generate dtd from xsd.